# Error when deploying SharePoint site content type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to create sample content type.Created a content type project in Visual  Studio 2010.Changed `element.xml` file as follows.I am getting an error when deploying the project.

> Error 1   Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Invalid
>   field name. {a93394f6-c085-4df0-b6b7-66a581e7c183}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <Field ID="{A93394F6-C085-4DF0-B6B7-66A581E7C183}" Name="ContactType"    DisplayName="Contact Type" Type ="Choice" >
<CHOICES>
  <CHOICE>Personal Contact</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Official Contact</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Other Contact</CHOICE>
</CHOICES>
</Field>
<ContentType ID="0x01002e9407b0368e4865936ac2e0ae45b8e8"
           Name="ContentSample - ContentType1"
           Group="Custom Content Types"
           Description="My Content Type"
           Inherits="TRUE"
           Version="0">
<FieldRefs>
  <FieldRef ID="{A93394F6-C085-4DF0-B6B7-66A581E7C183}"/>
</FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add the `Name` attribute to your `FieldRef` in the Content Type:

```
<FieldRef ID="{A93394F6-C085-4DF0-B6B7-66A581E7C183}" Name="ContactType" />
```

Comment: OK.I have tried it and working fine